# WAMP is running very slow

Tags: php, localhost, wampserver

I am using **WAMP** (*localhost*) on Windows 7.

When I am running my *localhost* it takes more than 1 minute to load the page. There are no queries or database connectivity. If it's just an HTML page, it also takes the same time, and if the Internet is connected it works normally.
**If Internet is connected it works perfectly. When the Internet is not available it takes more than 1 minutes to load a simple page.**

How can I fix this?

Comment: You surely have something in that HTML page that requires an internet connection. Can be, for example, a JS external file, a social widget (Facebook, Twitter, ...), images, etc...

Comment: Look at the relation section, there is similar issues discussed

Comment: Does page includes external link or fetching images/block/js from external links??

Comment: he doesn't say that it stops loading after 1 minute and the page is broken, just that it takes long time to load.

Comment: possible duplicate of [wamp/xampp localhost responding very slow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8432601/wamp-xampp-localhost-responding-very-slow)

Comment: Excellent answer here - https://www.devside.net/wamp-server/wamp-is-running-very-slow

Comment: my experience: wamp running slow was directly related to xdebug module. disable, and comment all xdebug related configurations from php.ini. That solved my issue.

Answer (score 51):

The solution that worked for me was to disable the **cgi_module**. Use one of these methods:

**(Method 1)** Left click on WAMP > Apache > Apache Modules > uncheck **"cgi_module"**

**(Method 2)** Edit **httpd.conf** and disable the loading of the CGI module by commenting this line:

```
LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
```

Commenting would be just adding a **#** in front, like this:

```
#LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
```

Restart the Apache service and you should be good to go.

Comment: I suggest doing this as well

Comment: I think this helped. Not sure but it seems to be an improvement.

Comment: Worked for me as well! Thank you! (WAMPSERVER 3.1.3 64bit)

Comment: What if I am using python, can I disable mod_cgi.so. Suddenly my application become slow

Answer (score 32):

Set mysql_connect('127.0.0.1'... instead of mysql_connect('localhost'....

[WAMP/XAMPP is responding very slow over localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8432601/wamp-xampp-localhost-responding-very-slow)

Comment: Wow, thanks! This works great for me! Went from rendering a simple page with some HTML, CSS and a MySQL connection (no queries) in 1.04 seconds down to 0.02 seconds. That's quite an improvement!

Comment: Confirmed! Went from 10 seconds loading to INSTANT. Will never localhost again...

Comment: My console log time went down to 129ms from 1m 5s. Thanks.

Comment: This worked for me!  Thanks man...been trying to track this down for months.

Comment: Where does this get changed?

Answer (score 17):

I tried a lot of the answers on here without much success. It was PHP itself where the bottleneck was occurring. I disabled Xdebug and my page-load time went from ~1200 ms to ~275 ms. That was where the biggest single gain occurred, by far.

Comment: Same goes with Zend Debugger. It slows down my apache by 5-10 times on Windows 10.

Comment: I disabled xdebug and changed db host to 127.0.0.1. Now my localhost is 20x faster! Thanks a lot

Comment: Huge gain for me on win7 using laravel for big requests, went from 13s to 3s just by disabling Xdebug

Answer (score 8):

Instead of using the hostname “localhost”, use an IP address in your MySQL connection string.

Typically, your WAMP installation is found in `C:\wamp`.
Edit this file with [Notepad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad_%28software%29):

```
C:\wamp\www\wp-config.php
```

Replace

```
define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
```

with

```
define("DB_HOST", "127.0.0.1");
```

Restart the WAMP services.

You can check out more details on [this website](https://web.archive.org/web/20150930194225/http://www.boonigo.com/slow-wamp-on-windows-8-1/).

Comment: Nothing else worked for me but This solution worked like a charm.

Comment: I think you're talking about the WordPress config. The question is about WAMP.

Comment: The link (`www.boonigo.com`) is completely broken.

Answer (score 3):

Changing the PHP SMTP server in file `php.ini` from `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`, on line 1084 in my vanilla copy, did the trick.

Answer (score 3):

Accessing my local content on `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` worked for me (so probably a DNS resolve issue is hidden somewhere):

- `http://127.0.0.1/mysite` is fast
- `http://localhost/mysite` is slow

Answer (score 3):

Here is a list of changes I made to make WAMP faster in my Windows 10 Pro 64 bit:

1. Edited *hosts* file and added: `127.0.0.1       localhost`
2. Edited *hosts* file and added: `127.0.0.1       myVhosts` (*note: I added all other entries in the same line as the first one. I don't create multiple lines to point 127.0.0.1 to different places. So I only have one 127.0.0.1 and then next to it, any vhosts or anything else that I want to point to it*)
3. Edited *my.ini* and added: `bind-address="127.0.0.1"` (below *[wampmysqld64]*)
4. Disabled *cgi_module* from Apache** → *Apache Modules* → *cgi_module* (uncheck it)
5. Disabled *XDEBUG Extension* from *php.ini*
6. As I have Anti-Virus and Firewall, added *httpd.exe* and *mysqld.exe* files (as well as PHP CLI and CGI binaries, and PHP’s DLL files) to the exceptions.
7. Turned on *EnableMMAP* and *EnableSendfile* in *httpd.conf*
8. Set *realpath_cache_size* to *4096k* in *php.ini*
9. In the end, edited the configuration file of projects and replaced the *localhost* with *127.0.0.1* as well.

I also recommend checking this article: *[WAMP is Running Very Slow](https://www.devside.net/wamp-server/wamp-is-running-very-slow)*. They covered a lot of changes that may help you as well.

Answer (score 2):

Uncommenting this line in the [hosts file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)) worked for me:

```
# 'localhost' name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
    127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
```

Uncommenting `127.0.01   localhost`. And after that it's super fast.

Comment: This works for me only if I leave # ::1, so only 127.0.0.1 uncommentet

Answer (score 2):

I'm running Windows 8, and WAMP was very slow. I did all suggested before. With a difference; WAMP had `httpd.conf` by default:

```
AcceptFilter http none
AcceptFilter https none
```

So I did the contrary thinking: Maybe this is not needed any more. It seems to work fine:

```
 #AcceptFilter http none
 #AcceptFilter https none
```

Maybe is not a problem in all Windows versions. In httpd you read:

```
# AcceptFilter: On Windows, none uses accept() rather than AcceptEx() and
# will not recycle sockets between connections. This is useful for network
# adapters with broken driver support, as well as some virtual network
# providers such as vpn drivers, or spam, virus or spyware filters.
#AcceptFilter http none
#AcceptFilter https none
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding to [tvanc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10750964/wamp-is-running-very-slow/26247091#26247091), also disable the Xdebug profiler in `php.ini` with `xdebug.profiler_enable=Off` or `xdebug.profiler_enable=0`.

You might also increase the PHP memory limit. Search for `memory_limit` in `php.ini`.

There are also some useful tips at *[WAMP is Running Very Slow](https://www.devside.net/wamp-server/wamp-is-running-very-slow)* which are too numerous to list here.

Comment: There is a long list of things that make a wamp Pro on macos slow. With me it was the profiling setting in php.ini file. Without knowing I enabled XDebug Profiling, which wrote out with every request files of the size of 300MB. Of course things went wrong and rendering a site took 1Min. Thanks for pointing this out

Answer (score 1):

My problem was of a smaller scale. An empty PHP page went from almost instant rendering to about 1 second.

It turned out that my Xdebug settings were causing the problem. I had `xdebug.remote_enable=on` set in the `php.ini` file, and this was causing the delay. Before I was starting, the debug session was using an idekey, so I only got the delay when starting a debug session. Commenting the line out solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Turning off the cgi_module also worked for me with WAMP + WordPress. I wanted to share that you can also do this with the WYSIWYG in [WampServer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WampServer) 2.5.

- Click on the WAMP Quick Launch Icon in the Taskbar.
- Hover over *Apache* → *Apache Modules*
- Click to remove the check mark from cgi_module

WAMP should restart itself, and you should see the speed pick up.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was plaguing me after I upgraded [WAMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAMP) Server from 2.2 to 2.4.

I eventually found the solution, as detailed in this blog post:
*[Apache server 2.4.6 hangs after serving requests from Internet Explorer 10/11](https://stijndewitt.com/2014/01/10/apache-hangs-ie11/)*

Add the following to Apache's configuration file (httpd.conf):

```
AcceptFilter http none
AcceptFilter https none
```

Answer (score 0):

This may sound really simple, but if you are using [Notepad++'s](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B) menu *Run* → *Launch in <browser>* option (e.g. *Launch in Firefox*), it loads as `file:///C:/wamp/www/dynamic/index.php` instead of `localhost/dynamic/index.php`.

If this is the case then try going to localhost/dynamic/index.php in the URL bar on your own, and it will load much faster.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue specifically in Chrome. Emptying the browser cache completely solved it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the slowness was because I was on a corporate [VPN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network) and also had a proxy URL set in Chrome. Off the VPN everything loaded fast.

To get things to work on the VPN, I removed the proxy setting from Chrome. Things mostly worked then, but a search for WordPress  plugins or themes from the dashboard still failed.

I added the following to wp-config.php and then search worked too:

```
 /** proxy settings */
 define('WP_PROXY_HOST', 'proxy.url.com');
 define('WP_PROXY_PORT', '1234');
 define('WP_PROXY_USERNAME', '');
 define('WP_PROXY_PASSWORD', '');
 define('WP_PROXY_BYPASS_HOSTS', 'localhost');
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and changed all the options mentioned.

After that, I saw that a Drupal database with extreme weight was causing the problem. Clearing the watchdog table and cache solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything, and nothing worked. Then I found out by removing all session references WAMP was 20 times faster. As the sessions were being locked, so when the same application requested multiple pages it was super slow.

Answer (score 0):

I followed all these and the links with no joy. Gold for my Wamp v7.3.16-2 was setting
**bind-address=::**
in MySQL's my.ini file. Response time went from minimum of 2 seconds to zero.

Thanks to http://regularcoder.com/tutorial/wamp-optimization-for-better-performance/#comment-30

Answer (score -1):

I've found that it somehow helps a lot not to reload the page, but rather go to another page, and click the link (if it it exists) to the previous page

I do this, since I have a menu bar, so I just click another link, and then back.

Answer (score -1):

Run WAMP only. Quit other applications which use the Internet.

Answer (score -2):

Add `127.0.0.1` as your DNS in *Use the following DNS server addresses* → *Preferred DNS server*