# Laravel 4.1 is 10x slower than 4.0

Tags: php, performance, laravel-4

I have just tried with Laravel 4.1 using a project which I half way develop with Laravel 4.0. After I move everything over to clean new Laravel 4.1, everything running ok. However, one thing that is truly unacceptable is the slowness of Laravel 4.1. All webpages loads extremely slow. Everything I tried were running on my local PC with WampServer.

On Laravel 4.0, a webpage take about 97ms to load. However, on Laravel 4.1, the same page take about 1.14s to load. It is more than 10 times slower.

Do you experience the same problem like me on new Laravel? Is there any possible I can improve the speed?

Thanks.

Comment: You've probably missed a setting, or loading more stuff than you need... Check out the config differences between the two versions.

Comment: What amazes me is that you had it running so quickly before. I use Xampp locally, and Laravel has always been slow on that. I was worried when I first started with laravel, because it looked unacceptable. However, once I uploaded it to the server it ran really fast.

Comment: Frankly I'm amazed you managed to get Laravel to load anything in 97ms. It is horrendously slow.  Did you update everything via composer?  Perhaps there's an incompatibility with a package?

Comment: No way is it slow. When I had it running a full site on my production server it was fine.

Comment: Guys, after I change the Apache server from version 2.2.17 to version 2.2.22, now it seems running normal. The webpage now took about 100ms to load.

Comment: tried php artisan optimize ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to upgrade your Apache Server. It should run faster.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MySql then check your config. Is the host set to "localhost"? Try to change it to 127.0.0.1. See [WAMP/XAMPP is responding very slow over localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8432601/wamp-xampp-localhost-responding-very-Slow) for more.