# WAMP displaying a page hangs occasionally (Windows 8.1)

Tags: wamp, freeze

Sometimes when I open a page in the browser, it hangs. Sometimes it loads after I've pressed refresh a few times, other times it only loads once I've loaded some other pages first, and sometimes I just have to wait a while. (Restarting all services always seems to fix the problem, but only temporarily). How can I diagnose the problem?

- WAMP Version 2.4 Française
- Apache Version :2.4.4
- PHP Version :5.4.12
- MySQL Version :5.6.12

I'm running the server on localhost with more or less default WAMP settings. None of the CPU cores are maxed out. It happens with the web app I'm developing, as well as phpmyadmin and other web apps. [rant supressed]

Comment: Check out this article: http://www.ducky-pond.com/posts/2014/Feb/fix-apache-24-hanging-on-a-wamp-server/

Comment: Check the answers provided in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8432601