# Enabling XDebug in XAMPP slows down phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp, xdebug

whenever i enable xdebug for debugging my php-projects with the following standard settings, it slows down phpmyadmin on every single action. just opening phpmyadmin takes nearly 10 seconds.

```
zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
xdebug.profiler_append = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"
xdebug.remote_enable = on
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
```

EDIT:
Trial and Error... this solved the problem

```
xdebug.remote_host = localhost
```

Comment: So by unloading the extension, won't slow it down?

Comment: I had same problem and after few days searching I found this :) Thanks

Comment: Another fix working for me: `xdebug.profiler_enable = 0`

Comment: @andrzej1_1 Thanks! This solved the slow resolving and enabled me to keep Xdebug running the way I wanted it to.

Comment: @andrzej1_1 Worked for me too. Been looking all over the place for a fix for this. Thanks.

Comment: I know we're not meant to add comments that just say thankyou...  but after a week of searching for the cause of this - THANKYOU!!! :)

Comment: https://hubpages.com/technology/Local-PHP-Debugging-with-XDebug-Atom-and-XAMPP hope this will help you

Answer (score 3):

In case xdebug.remote_autostart is enabled, disabling it with

```
xdebug.remote_autostart = 0
```

did the trick for me.

Comment: And if you need to debug PHP code (using XDebug), how do you start it (without re-editing the php.ini file)?

Answer (score -1):

disabling xdebug from the wamp php extension worked for me.

php > extensions > php_xdebug 2.8.0

Comment: the question is not how to disable it. Answer it appropriately.