# phpMyAdmin run very slowly and use too many CPU

Tags: mysql, apache, phpmyadmin, xampp, cpu

I am using phpMyAdmin, it run very slowly. For everything I do, I see loading dialogs in about 5-10 seconds. When I use phpMyAdmin, Apache use around 60% CPU.

When phpMyAdmin do something, Apache for one second changes ports to 55617 and 55618.

In my apps communication with database is not slow as in phpMyAdmin and Apache use CPU under 10% of.

Why?

**EDIT: SOLVED**. I remembered when it started and i think it started when i enable XDebug. I set `xdebug.profiler_enable = 0` and it works good.

[Enabling XDebug in XAMPP slows down phpmyadmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24893010/enabling-xdebug-in-xampp-slows-down-phpmyadmin#comment39305522_24893010)

Comment: SHOW PROCESSLIST -- what queries are you running?

Comment: screenshot: [link](http://misaz.moxo.cz/sended/phpmyadmin_slow.png)

Comment: Hmmm... Can't see to get the link to work.

Comment: On screenshot are two proceses. One by user pma and second by root. pma run command sleep on host http://localhost:69148 and root run Query on host http://localhost:69149. Info for root´s proces is 'SHOW PROCESSLIST'.