# Accessing localhost after installing WAMP

Tags: apache, server, localhost, wamp

I installed WAMP on my Windows 8.1, it was successfully installed, also when I click on start all services all services are started and the icon turns green. When I check port 80, it is used by Apache, but yet I cannot access http://localhost in my browser. Can someone help me? 
PS: I do not have Skype installed on my PC. I have recently refreshed my windows.

[This is my httpd.conf file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yqv1.jpg)

Comment: Check your hosts file to see where `localhost` is pointing to.

Comment: It is pointing to "127.0.0.1  localhost" without the quotes @Flosculus

Comment: Did you click "Put Server Online" in the menu?  The icon can be green and the server not be "online"...

Comment: @AndrewCoder No I didn't, where is that option available? When I start my services there is only "Put Offline" option

Comment: What browser are you using, **if its Chrome**, try another browser, does that work? Chrome has a few issues with `localhost`

Comment: If it's displayed as "Put Offline" then it is not related to my comment.  That's where it would say "Put Online"

Comment: @AndrewCoder It is **not necessary to Put Online** all that does is change the `httpd.conf` file to allow access from the universe. Something you should not do unless that is what you intend to do

Comment: Ahhh I see.  Good to know.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Well, localhost is accessible on Internet Explorer but not on chrome. Thanks. May I ask why it isn't accessible on Chrome?

Comment: **Yea I knew it**. Do a google on `"chrome localhost"` there are a number of ways to make it play nice, but they change almost with each upgrade, so its better you find the one that works for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WAMP/XAMPP is responding very slow over localhost](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8432601/wamp-xampp-is-responding-very-slow-over-localhost)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the apache httpd.conf file. Change `Listen 80` to `Listen 0.0.0.0:80`