# Xampp Wordpress admin

Tags: wordpress, xampp, localhost

I've justed moved my website to localhost using Xampp.
I changed some settings to increase speed and I can access every part of my site offline from `localhost:8080`, instead the `wp-admin`.
I can see the login page and I can enter my info to login, but when I hit enter it takes too much to load and I don't know even if it will be loaded or not, but when I connect to the internet, everything works well.
Currently, I can only see the pages and posts offline and WordPress doesn't respond.
What is wrong?

**Update**

I use `localhost:8080` to access my site, so I edited `wp-config.php` and changed

```
/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
```

to

```
/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost:8080');
```

but I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
>   nocache_headers() in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\wp-admin\admin.php:33
>   Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\wp-admin\index.php(10):
>   require_once() #1 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\wp-admin\admin.php on line 33

**Some of the changes I've made**

changing `Listen 127.0.0.1:80` to `Listen 127.0.0.1:8080` in `httpd.conf`

Comment: Edit question - add details - what settings have you changed to increase speed.

Comment: [First 4 tips in here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8432601/wamp-xampp-is-responding-very-slow-over-localhost-) @Zydnar

Answer (score 1):

There were wp files in the web root which had file size of 0 bytes.

Uploading proper copies from the zip file resolved the problem.

The same cause of the problem has occurred to me quite a few times in the past, but I had forgotten it.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem on my site. https://qtoestimating.com However, I was able to fix it temporarily by deleting the files with '0' size in the WordPress directory. But after a few hours, the error came again. So I finally sorted it out by doing a fresh WordPress installation and then shifting my WP-Content folder to new installation.