# mysql server is responding too slow or not responding

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I use mysql through phpmyadmin interface. i have no problem with the apache server. It responded,as it was before. But when i am trying to access the phpmyadmin page, the page is loading with a huge time. After a long time it came with a message

> `Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in
>   C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Dbi\DbiMysqli.php on line 213

` i have changed the value of the variable

> $cfg['ExecTimeLimit']

from 300 t0 1200. I think for that, i am able to see the loaded page. But, after loading i can't do anything with the interface as it takes too much time to respond.
I have tried the mentioned things in the following link 
[WAMP/XAMPP is responding very slow over localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8432601/wamp-xampp-is-responding-very-slow-over-localhost)

can anyone help me out to get rid of this problem, it's really waste a huge time of mine from several days

Comment: I suggest you download a MySQL tool ( like heidiSQL ) and connect to your local Mysql Server. So you can check if its the Mysql Server. If it runs in an acceptable time, then your Apache, PHP (CGI Module?) or PHPMyAdmin can cause the issue. Maybe after a backup, uninstall and fresh install the services responding as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem you could edit your php.ini file and set the max_execution_time = 120. But this isn't always working. Another suggestion is the past this two lines in your code. This solved my problem. It will affect the execution time of the script itself so it will get more time to run then the 30 seconds.

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
set_time_limit(0);
```

I don't know if you use this but this is the easiest way to visualise the errors.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```