# PHP MySQL large data set with lots of time to display in angular component and small csv file exported from database

Tags: php, mysql, json, localhost

**EDIT**

I selected only one field from all the query, the file size reduced to `433Kb` but the display time was 13 seconds.

**END OF EDIT**

I have the following query:

```
SELECT *,  DATE(h.hh_date_added) as dateOnly FROM unit u 
                    INNER JOIN househ h
                    ON u.unit_id=h.unit_id
                    LEFT JOIN location l
                    ON l.location_id_auto=u.location_id_auto
                    LEFT JOIN user us
                    ON us.user_id = h.user_id
                    ORDER BY dateOnly DESC
```

When running it on phpmyadmin, it is executed within 0.233 seconds returning 11331 row with nearly 20 fields.

If I export the data into csv or excel, the size of it would be 830Kb.

When returning this result using php to angular 6's `httpclient` service to display it in an angular material table:

```
getDataByType(){
    this.showSpinner=true;
    this.auth.getDataByType(this.dataType).subscribe(
      (data)=>
      {
        console.log(data)
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(Object.values(data));
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
        this.dataSource.sort=this.sort;
        this.showSpinner=false;
      },
      (error)=>
      {
        console.log("Error: "+error)
      }
    )


  }
```

It would take more than 30 seconds (As displayed in the content-download time) to the data to be displayed in the table and shown to the user.

The timing was displayed on the timing tab of google chrome network tab with a file size of `15.9 Mb`.

Why the file size is so huge ?

1. Is the problem from the material table that took too much time to display data after receiving them:

I don't think so, as testing it on `postman` returned the same file size with different time of 20 seconds.

2. or because of a query error which is returning a huge data set:

which I don't think so as on server computer, the result was returned within less than seconds with an excel file less than 1 Mb of size.

3. Is it because I am returning it as json encoded data and chrome is taking some time to handle it ?

No, because I try to send the data within an array without the use of `json_encode` function and still giving the same size even bigger (17Mb).

So is it local area network/router problem making the download time huge or other thing ?

Please refer to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53153459/php-and-wampserver-loading-data-on-users-computer-using-virtual-host-is-too-slow?noredirect=1) on stack to check the connection scripts to the local server.

Comment: Tip: NEVER use `SELECT *`

Comment: Okay, but if I need all fields ?

Comment: This would create redundancy - because FKs would be returned twice. However, if you really needed all columns, then you would name (and properly qualify)  all of them.

Comment: @Strawberry How can I do that ? By the way, I selected only field from the query, the file size reduced to 433 kb but the display time was 13 seconds.