# why does codeigniter slow down?

Tags: performance, codeigniter-3

I have build an website using `CI`. I run it on my office computer with `XAMPP`. Today I got it on my PC but it is loading very slow.

I have tried the benchmark tools. Even the empty pages without `queries` and `UI` are not loading with a normal speed.
I have checked the rewrite mod. It is ON.
Any ideas where i have to look?

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8432601/wamp-xampp-is-responding-very-slow-over-localhost

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to insufficient resources or limited specs of the host system. You may want to investigate whether there are any other processeses running that may be consuming excessive memory or CPU time. You should be able to find online instructions on how to do this for your system.

If that's not the case, you'd have to provide further details of your CI project such as a typical page load stack trace and or a link to a demonstrable version of your project / repository.